# PANDAS pivot table; sort by Numeric Bins

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a pivot table in PANDAs and am trying to sort the categorical-type bins that are created using pd.cut. However they sort in the order like this...
[1,3),[20,25),[3,8),[30,35),[8,20)

Here is my code. I've thought that perhaps I can format the bin labels with a string indicated "Bin 1_...","Bin2_...", etc...

```
df['tpb'] = df['tpb'].astype('float64')
bins2 = [0,1,2,4,8,15,25,50]
diff=np.diff(bins2).tolist()
joint = list(zip(bins2,diff))
s1 = "{left:,.0f} to {right:,.0f}"
labels2 = [s1.format(left=yr[0], right=yr[0]+yr[1]-1) for yr in joint]
df['tpb_bin'] = pd.cut(df['tpb'],bins2,right=False,labels=labels2)
table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['category','day','tpb_bin'],columns=['test_type'])
```

Comment: For me it sort correctly, I use test data `np.random.seed(100)` `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50, size=(30,4)), columns=['tpb', 'category', 'day', 'test_type'])` `print (df)`, then use `df['tpb_bin'] = pd.cut(df['tpb'],bins2,right=False)` and sorting correctly again. Maybe need upgrade pandas.

Comment: The simplier test sorting is by `print (df['tpb_bin'].sort_values())`